# tableselect does not work for me somehow 1

Tags: 7, forms

```
Array
(
    [table] => Array
        (
            [#type] => tableselect
            [#header] => Array
                (
                    [field_name] => FIELD NAME
                    [field_type] => FIELD TYPE
                    [no_of_values] => NO OF VALUES
                    [display_fields] => DISPLAY FIELDS
                    [field_label] => FIELD LABEL
                    [required] => Required
                    [product_type] => Product Type
                )

            [#options] => Array
                (





            [field_colour_pro] => Array
                        (
                            [field_name] => field_colour_pro
                            [field_type] => 
                            [no_of_values] => 
                            [display_fields] => 1
                            [field_label] => color
                            [required] => 0
                            [product_type] => shirt
                        )

                    [field_description] => Array
                        (
                            [field_name] => field_description
                            [field_type] => 
                            [no_of_values] => 
                            [display_fields] => 1
                            [field_label] => description
                            [required] => 0
                            [product_type] => test_pro_v
                        )

                )

            [#multiple] => 1
        )
```

---

```
$header = array(
    'field_name' => t('FIELD NAME'),
    'field_type' => t('FIELD TYPE'),
    'no_of_values' => t('NO OF VALUES'),
    'display_fields' => t('DISPLAY FIELDS'),
    'field_label' => t('FIELD LABEL'),
    'required' => t('Required'),
    'product_type' => t('Product Type'),
  );

  $rows = array();
  foreach(commerce_product_types() as $product_type => $product_type_array){
    $field_info = field_info_instances('commerce_product',$product_type);
    foreach($field_info as $machine_name =>$field_details){
      $rows[$machine_name] = array(
        'field_name' => $machine_name,
        'field_type' => $field_details['type'],
        'no_of_values' => $field_details['cardinality'],
        'display_fields'=>1,
        'field_label' => $field_details['label'],
        'required' => $field_details['required'],
        'product_type'=> $product_type,
      );

    }
  }

  $form['table'] = array(
    '#type' => 'tableselect',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#options' => $rows,
    '#multiple' => TRUE,
  );

//  print_r($form);
  $form['save'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Save'),
  );

return $form;
```

---

I tried to get the tableselect form #type into operation it does not work and gives empty row even when each row has values,I would like to help me find any silly mistake which I am making out here

Here is image of how the table select looks which is empty 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I copied your code from and commented the variables and/or functions you're using since I don't know what they are for and just replaced a simple array to loop through.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function leomod_menu() {
  $items['leoo'] = array(
    'title' => 'asd',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('leomod_asd_form'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );
  return $items;
}

/**
 * Form.
 */
function leomod_asd_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $header = array(
    'field_name' => t('FIELD NAME'),
    'field_type' => t('FIELD TYPE'),
    'no_of_values' => t('NO OF VALUES'),
    'display_fields' => t('DISPLAY FIELDS'),
    'field_label' => t('FIELD LABEL'),
    'required' => t('Required'),
    'product_type' => t('Product Type'),
  );

  $rows = array();
  $tests = array('1', '2', '3');
  //foreach(commerce_product_types() as $product_type => $product_type_array){
  foreach($tests as $test) {
    // $field_info = field_info_instances('commerce_product',$product_type);
    //foreach($field_info as $machine_name =>$field_details){
      $rows[$test] = array(
        'field_name' => $test,
        'field_type' => $test,
        'no_of_values' => $test,
        'display_fields'=> $test,
        'field_label' => $test,
        'required' => $test,
        'product_type'=> $test,
      );
    //}
  }

  $form['table'] = array(
    '#type' => 'tableselect',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#options' => $rows,
    '#multiple' => TRUE,
  );

  //  print_r($form);
  $form['save'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Save'),
  );

  return $form;
}
```

Since your table structure is working, I suspect there is something wrong with these lines:

```
foreach(commerce_product_types() as $product_type => $product_type_array) {
```

and

```
$field_info = field_info_instances('commerce_product',$product_type);
foreach($field_info as $machine_name =>$field_details) {
```

Also make sure you:

1. Flushed caches
2. [Show all errors while developing](https://www.drupal.org/node/1056468) since you're dealing with functions there that may return some errors that aren't displayed
3. Check the variables and functions if they return anything by using print_r() or Devel module's dsm().

Answer (score 0):

Check that the function (presumably buildForm()) implements "FormStateInterface".  Drupal will render a table w/o children if not done from within such a function.  See: [tableselect form doesn't work](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/230076/tableselect-form-doesnt-work).