# tableselect form doesn't work

Tags: 8, forms

I can't get form-table of '#type' => 'tableselect' to work.  I've lifted the example from [8.3.x core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element/Tableselect.php Tableselect](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Tableselect.php/class/Tableselect/8.3.x). The table works and there are no log messages.

What happens is the page reports that there are no users found (ie. the table is empty) even though the $form array has the row data in it.

If I change the type to '#type' => 'table' the table is populated as expected.

This is the code I am using.

```
namespace Drupal\simpleForm\Controller;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class DisplayTable_1 extends ControllerBase
{

    public function description_one()
    {
        $header = [
            'first_name' => $this->t('First Name'),
            'last_name' => $this->t('Last Name'),
        ];

        $options = [
            1 => ['first_name' => 'Indy', 'last_name' => 'Jones'],
            2 => ['first_name' => 'Darth', 'last_name' => 'Vader'],
            3 => ['first_name' => 'Super', 'last_name' => 'Man'],
        ];

        $form['table'] = array(
            '#type' => 'tableselect',
            '#header' => $header,
            '#options' => $options,
            '#empty' => $this->t('No users found!!!'),
        );

        return $form;
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Clearing cache makes no difference.

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue: the **#type' => 'tableselect** has to be built inside a class that extends **FormBase**.

This Works:

```
  class DisplayTable_1 extends FormBase {
    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
    {
        $options = [
            1 => ['first_name' => 'Indy', 'last_name' => 'Jones'],
            2 => ['first_name' => 'Darth', 'last_name' => 'Vader'],
            3 => ['first_name' => 'Super', 'last_name' => 'Man'],
        ];

        $header = [
            'first_name' => t('First Name'),
            'last_name' => t('Last Name'),
        ];

        $form['table'] = [
            '#type' => 'tableselect',
            '#title' => $this->t('Users'),
            '#header' => $header,
            '#options' => $options,
            '#empty' => t('No users found'),
        ];

        // Add a submit button that handles the submission of the form.
        $form['actions']['submit'] = [
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
            '#description' => $this->t('Submit, #type = submit'),
        ];
        return $form;
    }

    public function getFormId() {
        return 'fapi_example_input_demo_form';
    }

    public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        // Find out what was submitted.
        $values = $form_state->getValues();
        foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
            $label = isset($form[$key]['#title']) ? $form[$key]['#title'] : $key;

            // Many arrays return 0 for unselected values so lets filter that out.
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $value = array_filter($value);
            }

            // Only display for controls that have titles and values.
            if ($value && $label) {
                $display_value = is_array($value) ? preg_replace('/[\n\r\s]+/', ' ', print_r($value, 1)) : $value;
                $message = $this->t('Value for %title: %value', array('%title' => $label, '%value' => $display_value));
                drupal_set_message($message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, ControllerBase would not provide any form building capabilities.

Comment: Any way to use tableselect outside the form?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$header = [
  'first_name' => ['data' => $this->t('First Name')],
  'last_name' => ['data' => $this->t('Last Name')],
   ...
 ];

$options = [
    1 => ['first_name' => ['data' => ['#title' => 'Indy']], 'last_name' => ['data' => ['#title' => 'Jones']],
    ...
];
```

I checked the code [over here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21comment%21src%21Form%21CommentAdminOverview.php/function/CommentAdminOverview%3A%3AbuildForm/8.3.x).

Comment: Remy, I'm afraid that did not work.